# django-channels not working/not sendind any messages as web socket

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

by following one of those tutorials over youtube
i have just wrote a websocket server using django-channels
here is my code 
signal.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def announce_new_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            "gossip", {"type": "user_gossip",
                       "event": "New User",
                       "username": instance.username})
```

consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer


class NoseyConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        await self.channel_layer.group_add("gossip", self.channel_name)
        print(f"Added {self.channel_name} channel to gossip")

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard("gossip", self.channel_name)
        print(f"Removed {self.channel_name} channel to gossip")

    async def user_gossip(self, event):
        await self.send_json(event)
        print(f"Got message {event} at {self.channel_name}")
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class NotifierConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'notifier'
    def ready(self):
        from .import signals
```

**init**.py

```
default_app_config = 'notifier.apps.NotifierConfig'
```

routing.py

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.urls import path
from notifier.consumers import NoseyConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": URLRouter([
        path("notifications/", NoseyConsumer),
    ])
})
```

and in channels_layers in settings.py

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost",16379)],
        },
    },
}
```

i dont know what the issue is when ever i  create a new user using admin i cant see any kind of data that is being transmitted from django websockets over the console and tried  a lot figuring out the issue but still its of no use

here is my client javascript code

```
<html>
   <head>

      <script type = "text/javascript">




               // Let us open a web socket
               var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/notifications/");

               var msg = "hi, this is simple message.";
               ws.onopen = function(evt) {
                 ws.send(msg);
               };
               ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
                 // handle this message
                 console.log(evt.username);
               };
               ws.onclose = function(evt) {
                 // this channel is closed
               };
               ws.onerror = function(evt) {
                 // handle this error
               };


      </script>

   </head>

   <body>


   </body>
</html>
```

and when  i tried to acces the same website by adding the user here what i got in the terminal

```
   HTTP GET / 200 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:55829]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /notifications/ [127.0.0.1:55935]
WebSocket CONNECT /notifications/ [127.0.0.1:55935]
Added specific.pgRlAson!hqgpORLfvfbO channel to gossip
Exception inside application: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 59, in __call__
    [receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch
  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\channels\utils.py", line 52, in await_many_dispatch
    await dispatch(result)
  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 73, in dispatch

    await handler(message)
  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\channels\generic\websocket.py", line 196, in websocket_
receive
    await self.receive(text_data=message["text"])
  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\channels\generic\websocket.py", line 259, in receive
    await self.receive_json(await self.decode_json(text_data), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\channels\generic\websocket.py", line 277, in decode_jso
n
    return json.loads(text_data)
  File "c:\users\madhumani\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "c:\users\madhumani\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "c:\users\madhumani\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
WebSocket DISCONNECT /notifications/ [127.0.0.1:55935]
```

Comment: Please edit the post to reflect the changes you made to your code based on my answer. Again, are you sure the connection is alive at the time the signal is sent and that the signal is in fact being sent? Can you also add a print statement to the signal handler to ensure that the connect print statement is directly followed by the signal print statement?

Comment: question updated :-) i could see none of those print statements in my terminal  while i run the code or add an user and please could you elaborate to which of those should i add print statements  ,so sorry im having zero knowledge on how those channels work underhood

Comment: If you don't see the print statements, then the client you're trying to send a message to, is not connected so of course the message can't be sent. I meant you should add a print statement in the `announce_new_user` receiver method. Is your client connected by websocket to the server??

Comment: i have added a print statement to  line 4 in signals.py  and here is the project of that tutorial  https://github.com/arocks/channels-example/tree/UserNotif  please have a look ,so being a newbie everything is too confusing for me

Comment: If the print statement in `connect` is not being shown, then the answer is quite simple - your js client has not connected to the server. So check the js code in the templates and the browser developer tools to ensure that the js client to getting connected

Comment: @Ken4scholars bro question has been updated please can you have a look at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186866/discussion-between-mounikes-mintu-and-ken4scholars).